# Drop down in watir 6.8.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

This is my code for drop down selection using ruby:

ruby version is 2.4.3

watir version 6.8.4

cucumber version 3.01

firefox version 47

```
b.select(id: 'curLocation').option(text: 'Chennai').select
```

This code is not working for me.

Comment: Can you please include the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.start 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
s = b.select_list id: 'entry_1000001'
s.select'Ruby'
s.selected_options
```

Reference: [watir](http://watir.com/guides/elements/)

Answer (score 0):

```
select_from_list = browser.select_list(:xpath, "xpath")
                        .option(:text => opts[:yourjson])
select_from_list.select
```

Its for example.
I hope it will help you

Exactly - you can use .option(:xpath, "xpath")
or                    .option(code: "xpath")

Answer (score -1):

You are using `#select` wrong. Take a look at [the specs](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/spec/watirspec/elements/select_list_spec.rb#L232) for more examples, but all you have to do is:

```
b.select(id: 'curLocation').select('Chennai')
```

Also, Firefox 47 isn't a supported version any longer. Please update to the latest version of Firefox, and the latest [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Also your title says Watir 6.8.4, but you list 5.1.4, which is deprecated.

Comment: No, her syntax is correct. she used in the right way. `b.select().option().select ` is one of the other systax to choose the option.

Comment: The code I'm showing has extra waiting logic that might be necessary here. Watir 7 will distinguish between `#select` and `#select_all` to allow it to be more performant, but it is still the syntactically encouraged signature.

Comment: You did not mention that, You said "You are using #select wrong. " but she is using rightly, no problem with her syntax.